# A version of colorbox that works inside math environments

Tags: color, boxes, amsmath

I'd like to highlight particular parts of an amsmath environment.  Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,color}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\newcommand{\Abs}[1]{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert}

%\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}
\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{\boxed{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \ell \\
\iff& \forall \epsilon > 0, \, \exists \delta > 0 \text{ s.t. if }
0 < \abs{\Delta x - 0} < \delta,
\text{ then } \Abs{\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} - \ell} < \epsilon \\
\iff& \forall \epsilon > 0, \, \exists \delta > 0 \text{ s.t. if }
0 < \highlight{\abs{x - x_0}} < \delta, \text{ then }
\highlight{\Abs{\frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0} - \ell}} < \epsilon
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

If I change which version of the `\highlight` command is commented out, the compiler starts complaining about `Missing $ inserted`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The problem here is that `\colorbox` reverts it's argument back to text mode. And, since you're using math-related macros (like `\left`, `\right`, `\frac` and `\ell`) in text mode, TeX complains about a missing `$`. So you need to explicitly state that you're in math mode using:

```
\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{$\displaystyle #1$}}
```

I've added the `\displaystyle` to make sure your fractions and delimiters are expanded as usual. If this behaviour is unwanted, you can modify or remove it.

On that topic, [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides `\dfrac` which is short for `\displaystyle\frac`. Such explicit use of display/text style fractions works well to force one's intent, and would eliminate the use of `\displaystyle.`

[image]

---

It is possible to improve the `\highlight` macro to detect the type of math mode being used. This is possible by using `\mathchoice` which provides typesetting choices for 4 different styles:

```
\mathchoice{<displaystyle>}{<textstyle>}{<scriptstyle>}{<scriptscriptstyle>}
```

In the updated version of `\highlight` the math mode is detected prior to using `\colorbox`, and switched accordingly inside it. Additionally, for generalization, I've added an optional argument to `\highlight` that allows you to switch the colour (default is `yellow`) as showcased in the MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\newcommand{\Abs}[1]{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert}

% \highlight[<colour>]{<stuff>}
\newcommand{\highlight}[2][yellow]{\mathchoice%
  {\colorbox{#1}{$\displaystyle#2$}}%
  {\colorbox{#1}{$\textstyle#2$}}%
  {\colorbox{#1}{$\scriptstyle#2$}}%
  {\colorbox{#1}{$\scriptscriptstyle#2$}}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  & \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \ell \\
  \iff & \forall \epsilon > 0, \, \exists \delta > 0 \text{ s.t. if }
    0 < \abs{\Delta x - 0} < \delta,
    \text{ then } \Abs{\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} - \ell} < \epsilon \\
\iff & \forall \epsilon > 0, \, \exists \delta > 0 \text{ s.t. if }
    0 < \highlight{\abs{x - x_0}} < \delta, \text{ then }
    \highlight[green]{\Abs{\frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0} - \ell}} < \epsilon
\end{alignat*}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not accepting this immediately, but only because of the possibility that someone might supply code that make sure the style inside the colorbox matches the style outside the colorbox. (For instance, I might want to use the same \highlight command elsewhere for an inline fraction, or conceivably even for text.) But this solution certainly works.

Comment: @CharlesStaats: I've updated my answer to accommodate a variable choice in math style using `\mathchoice`... and spruced it up a little with an optional argument for colour changes.

Comment: This is great! Answer accepted.  (I did not know about `\mathchoice`, and I'm very pleased to learn about it.)

Comment: By the way, I have to ask: Is there a good reason here to use `xcolor` instead of `color`?

Comment: @CharlesStaats: My reason for loading [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) is three-fold: (1) It loads [`color`](http://ctan.org/pkg/color) by default and (2) it provides an easy user interface which extends that of `color`, allowing one to use colour shades and mixes without formally defining them first. For example, you can use `\color{black!15}` (15% black) or `\color{yellow!30!green}` (30% yellow, 70% green), without figuring our what the RGB components of it is and using `\color[rgb]{?,?,?}` or `\definecolor{<col>}{...}`. (3) Finally, it has a *large* set of predefined colour names.

Answer (score 6):

Another way is to use `\ensuremath`:

```
\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{\ensuremath{#1}}}
```

This has also the desired effect.

Comment: The issue is that this doesn't re-enables the correct form of mathmode, like `\displaymode`.

Answer (score 4):

I have some code for highlighting text that is specifically designed for use with the beamer class.  It uses TikZ, but I load TikZ anyway in my presentations so that's no extra overhead.  The main features of this solution are:

1. The same code is for text as maths,
2. The highlighting is drawn on the background canvas and so is *behind* the text,
3. The style of the highlighter is considerably customisable via PGF keys,
4. It does a reasonable job of line wrapping.

It is possible to adapt this to a non-beamer solution, either using Martin Scharer's code for drawing on the background of a page, or adapting beamer's (ab)use of headers to place code behind the text.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
%
% Highlighter code
%

\newbox\high@box
\let\high@contents=\@empty
\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{highlighter}{%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{background canvas}{}{\color{bg}\vrule width\paperwidth height\paperheight}%
  \begingroup
  \setbox\high@box=\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[minimum width=\textwidth, minimum height=\textheight, anchor=south east] (page) at (-\beamer@rightmargin,\footheight) {};
    \high@contents
  \end{tikzpicture}}%
  \wd\high@box=0pt\ht\high@box=0pt\dp\high@box=0pt%
    \vbox{\hbox{\box\high@box}}%
  \global\let\high@contents=\@empty
  \endgroup}

\newcommand{\addtobg}[1]{%
  \g@addto@macro\high@contents{#1}%
}

\newcounter{highlight}
\newcommand{\hlstart}{\tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline=-0.7ex] \coordinate (hlstart\the\value{highlight});\hl@start}
\newcommand{\hlend}{\tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline=-0.7ex] \coordinate (hlend\the\value{highlight});\hl@end\stepcounter{highlight}}

\newcommand{\hl@start}[1][]{%
  \edef\@temp{%
    \noexpand\addtobg{{\noexpand\tikzset{#1}\noexpand\hl@draw{\the\value{highlight}}}}%
  }%
  \@temp
}

\newcommand{\hl@end}{}

\newcommand{\hl@draw}[1]{%
  \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/highlighter width}{\hl@width}%
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\hl@width}{\hl@width - 1pt}%
  \path (hlstart#1);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\hl@sx}{\hl@sy}%
  \path (hlend#1);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\hl@ex}{\hl@ey}%
  \ifdim\hl@sy=\hl@ey\relax
  \draw[highlight] (hlstart#1) -- (hlend#1);
  \else
  \draw[highlight] (hlstart#1) -- (hlstart#1 -| page.east);
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\hl@sy}{\hl@sy -\hl@width}%
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\hl@ey}{\hl@ey +\hl@width}%
  \loop\ifdim\hl@sy>\hl@ey\relax
  \draw[highlight] (0,\hl@sy -| page.west) -- (0,\hl@sy -| page.east);
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\hl@sy}{\hl@sy -\hl@width}%
  \repeat
  \draw[highlight] (hlend#1 -| page.west) -- (hlend#1);
  \fi
}

\tikzset{%
  highlight/.style={
    color=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/highlighter colour},
    line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/highlighter width},
    line cap=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/highlighter cap},
  },
  highlighter colour/.initial=yellow,
  highlighter width/.initial=12pt,
  highlighter cap/.initial=butt,
}

\setbeamercolor{highlighted text}{bg=yellow}

\newcommand<>{\highlight}[2][]{%
  \only#3{\hlstart[#1]}#2\only#3{\hlend}}

\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[highlighter]
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\newcommand{\Abs}[1]{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\small
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \ell \\
\iff& \forall \epsilon > 0, \, \exists \delta > 0 \text{ s.t. if }
0 < \abs{\Delta x - 0} < \delta,
\text{ then } \Abs{\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} - \ell} < \epsilon \\
\iff& \forall \epsilon > 0, \, \exists \delta > 0 \text{ s.t. if }
0 < \highlight{\abs{x - x_0}} < \delta, \text{ then }
\highlight[highlighter colour=green,highlighter width=1cm]{\Abs{\frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0} - \ell}} < \epsilon
\end{alignat*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

With a sample:

[image: highlighted text]

Comment: Is there a lot of changes to do so as to use your code for "no-beamer" documents ?

Comment: @projetmbc: No, not a lot.  But it does hack into the headers so if you had special headers you'd have to be careful with that (beamer already has this "feature") and for some reason I get an overfull hbox that I don't understand!