# multicols within colorbox

Tags: color, boxes, multicol

i'm trying to get a gray background for an entire multicols environment and get errors with this "minimal" working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
  \setlength{\parskip}{11pt}

  \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
      \colorbox{gray}{
        \begin{multicols}{2}
          \begin{description}

            \item[xyz] \hfill \\
            description

            \item[xyz] \hfill \\
            description

            \columnbreak

            \item[xyz] \hfill \\
            description

            \item[xyz] \hfill \\
            description
          \end{description}
        \end{multicols}
      }
    \end{center}
  \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

This generates a lot of errors on the closing "}" from the colorbox that make no sense for me.
If I comment the colorbox out it compiles without problems.

Something I guess is similar I hit while going through the suggestions:
[A version of colorbox that works inside math environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33401/a-version-of-colorbox-that-works-inside-math-environments)

Since one of the errormessages states that it's automatically creating a math environment/symbol i guess my problem is similar, though the answer to the question is just codesalad i don't understand and thus can't really use.

Any explained solution to either prevent LaTex to create a math-environment or getting a grey background under the multicol is highly appreciated.

Btw. i just started using LaTeX, so explanations are also highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\colorbox` is an `LR` box like `\mbox`. You can not nest vertical material directly in such a box, use

```
  \noindent
  \colorbox{gray}{%
  \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\begin{multicols}...
```

Comment: I just have one question left: which value does the \dimexpr... command return? And just to confirm that i understand it right: the \parbox creates a vertical box environment, which gives \multicols the environment it needs, right?

Comment: it is an (etex but supported in all current distributuons) syntax which expands to the value given using infix syntax (an alternative to using the `calc` package) you want a full width box but the `\parbox` can not be `\textwidth` wide as `\colorbox` like `\fbox` adds padding all round so there is an additional `\fboxsep` space added to each side that you need to subtract to get the size needed for the inner box.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some methods you can use:

- the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package;
- the [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package;
- a `tikzmark`-based solution (requires the library [`tikzmark`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files) - download the `.dtx` and compile to get the needed `tikzlibrarytikzmark.code.tex`).

The code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tikzbox}{m D(){0.1,-0.18} D(){-0.1,0.35}}{%
      \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
      \draw[line width=1pt,rectangle,rounded corners,fill=lightgray!50,draw=white]
      (pic cs:#1) ++(#2) rectangle (#3)
      ;}

\begin{document}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
  \setlength{\parskip}{11pt}

% With tcolorbox

  \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=white,colback=lightgray!50] 
        \begin{multicols}{2}
          \begin{description}

            \item[xyz] \hfill \\
            description

            \item[xyz] \hfill \\
            description

            \columnbreak

            \item[xyz] \hfill \\
            description

            \item[xyz] \hfill \\
            description
          \end{description}
        \end{multicols}
      \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{titlepage}

% Using mdframed

   \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=lightgray!50,linecolor=white]
        \begin{multicols}{2}       
          \begin{description}
            \item[xyz] \hfill \\
            description

            \item[xyz] \hfill \\
            description

            \columnbreak

            \item[xyz] \hfill \\
            description

            \item[xyz] \hfill \\
            description
          \end{description}
        \end{multicols}
      \end{mdframed}  
  \end{titlepage}

     \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{multicols}{2}

          \begin{description}
            \item[\tikzbox{a}xyz]   \hfill \\
            description

            \item[xyz] \hfill \\
            description

            \columnbreak

            \item[xyz] \hfill \\
            description

            \item[xyz] \hfill \\
            description    \tikzmark{a}        
          \end{description}          
        \end{multicols}
  \end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

The three results:

- with `tcolorbox`:

[image]

- with `mdframed`:

[image]

- with `tikzmark`:

[image]

Notice that the `tikzmark` solution provides a strict box around the text: if you want to extend, it is possible, you can refer to [Issues and potentiality of the tikzmark macro: dynamic box adaptation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/issues-and-potentiality-of-the-tikzmark-macro-dynamic-box-adaptation#57655) because the `\tikzbox` command has the so called *extensible markers*.