# How would I set up a separate page of references at the end of the flashcard document class?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, flashcards

As I would like to occasionally reference certain results or more sources in my flashcards, I tried to find a way to display the reference entries in my `.bib` file at the end of my flashcard document as separate, succeeding page(s) (in a similar way as they appear in the `article` documentclass for instance).

With the document class being fixed to [`flashcards`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/flashcards) in the preamble, I could not find a way how to set up a reference page that ignores the `flashcards` layout and simply prints one or more pages with the heading *References* followed by several, cited bibitem entries, displayed as defined in the `bibliographystyle` command.

---

### `main.tex` file

Here is a small working example for my flashcard document, with one flashcard citing an arXiv article. I use `\nobibliography{...}`, but of course to achieve a reference page one has to write the `\bibliography{...}` instead. However, this not only produces an ill-formated `Reference` at the top of the `.pdf` but also errors. Is there some way to circumvent this?

```latex
\documentclass[avery5371, grid]{flashcards}

\cardfrontstyle[\small\slshape]{headings}
\cardbackstyle[\small]{empty}

% v. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115141/how-can-i-aboxed-a-matrix
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
        a4paper,
        total={210mm,297mm}, %instead of {210mm, 297mm}
        left=0mm,
        top=0mm,
}
%

%
\setlength{\cardheight}{74.25mm}  % 297/4 = 74.25
\setlength{\cardwidth}{105mm} % {a4-width} / 2 = 105 mm
\setlength{\topskip}{0mm}

\setlength{\cardmargin}{15 pt}
%

\cardfrontheadstyle[\bfseries\scshape]{left}
\cardfrontfootstyle[\small\itshape\em\bfseries]{right}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{ulem}



\usepackage{inlinebib}
% % v. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37747/which-package-for-oiint-symbol
\usepackage{esint} % various fancy integral symbols
% \usepackage{stix}


% in-math colorboxed, inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33401/a-version-of-colorbox-that-works-inside-math-environments 
\newcommand{\highlightg}[1]{\colorbox{green!40}{$\displaystyle #1$}}

\newcommand{\highlightb}[1]{\colorbox{blue!20}{$\displaystyle #1$}}

\newcommand{\highlightpink}[1]{\colorbox{red!40}{$\displaystyle #1$}}

\newcommand{\highlightorange}[1]{\colorbox{orange!40}{$\displaystyle #1$}}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for commands such as '\coloneqq'
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bold-extra}

\definecolor{my-lightblue}{HTML}{00aedb}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Rn}{\mathbb{R}^{n}}
\newcommand{\Rm}{\mathbb{R}^{m}}
\newcommand{\nbyn}{n\!\times\!n}
\newcommand{\nbym}{n\times m}


\begin{document}


\cardfrontfoot{GRT}


%=========================================================%

\begin{flashcard}[{\color{my-lightblue} Definition} {\normalfont - \textbf{25.1.} Concepts of GRT}]{Front Page}

Explanations ...\citet{TahaS_VectorCalculus_prePrint}

\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\end{flashcard}



\begin{flashcard}[{\color{my-lightblue} Definition} {\normalfont - \textbf{25.1.} Concepts of GRT}]{Front Page}

Explanations ...

\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\end{flashcard}

%=========================================================%

\begin{flashcard}[{\color{my-lightblue} Definition} {\normalfont - \textbf{25.1.} Concepts of GRT}]{Front Page}

Explanations ...

\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\end{flashcard}



\begin{flashcard}[{\color{my-lightblue} Definition} {\normalfont - \textbf{25.1.} Concepts of GRT}]{Front Page}

Explanations ...

\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\end{flashcard}

%=========================================================%

\begin{flashcard}[{\color{my-lightblue} Definition} {\normalfont - \textbf{25.1.} Concepts of GRT}]{Front Page}

Explanations ...

\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\end{flashcard}



\begin{flashcard}[{\color{my-lightblue} Definition} {\normalfont - \textbf{25.1.} Concepts of GRT}]{Front Page}

Explanations ...

\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\end{flashcard}

%=========================================================%


\begin{flashcard}[{\color{my-lightblue} Definition} {\normalfont - \textbf{25.1.} Concepts of GRT}]{Front Page}

Explanations ...

\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\end{flashcard}



\begin{flashcard}[{\color{my-lightblue} Definition} {\normalfont - \textbf{25.1.} Concepts of GRT}]{Front Page}

Explanations ...

\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\end{flashcard}

%=========================================================%

\newpage
\nobibliography{References.bib} % for the purpose of getting a Reference page the \bib... must be uncommented of course, but this gives rise to not just an ugly formatted text but also errors...
% \bibliography{References.bib} 
\bibliographystyle{apalike} % e.g.: plainnat, apalike

\end{document}
```

---

### `References.bib` file

```
@article{TahaS_VectorCalculus_prePrint,
  author  = {{Taha}, Sochi}, 
  title   = {Tensor Calculus},
  journal = {arXiv pre-print},
  year    = {2016},
  number  = {},
  pages   = {},
  month   = {},
  note    = {\url{https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.04347}}, 
  volume  = 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here. The major one is that you want to add pages that aren't flashcards at the end of a flashcards document. I don't know if that is possible and suspect that the easiest way to do that would be to make two documents and then join them – which would be tricky here. So in this answer I ignore this and put the reference list on a flashcard instead. That will of course not be practical if it is too long.

The minor issue is that by default `\bibliography` will make a Chapter, but `\chapter` is not defined in the flashcards environment. I solve this by cheating and letting `\chapter` be a synonym of `\section`. You can see solutions that are less about cheating for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037905/bibliography-as-section-in-latex-bibtex).

I thought there was so much irrelevant stuff in your example, so I trimmed it down to a smaller example to make it clearer. Also I used one of the standard bibtex files to get something to cite so I wouldn't need an extra bib file.

```
\documentclass[avery5371, grid]{flashcards}

\cardfrontstyle{headings}
\cardbackstyle{empty}

\setlength{\cardheight}{50mm}
\setlength{\cardwidth}{80mm}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}

% By default \bibliography will make a \chapter,
% which is undefined in "flashcards".
\let\chapter\section
\begin{document}

\begin{flashcard}{Front Page}
  \citet{Knuth:ct-a}
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}{References}
  \bibliography{texbook1} 
  \bibliographystyle{apalike}
\end{flashcard}

\end{document}
```

Here the backs will look like this:

[image]

I realize this is not a full answer to your question, but hopefully still a bit useful.